# Python: syntax error when reading from file

Tags: python, file-io, syntax

I'm reading data from a file. Most of the data in the data file will be read in and written out to an output file without modification. However, in places the data is separated by a blank line, which precedes 5 other useless lines. Here is my code:

```
#Now loop over the entire file
while True:
testline = infile.readline()
if len(testline) ==0:
    break # EOF
elseif testline == '\n':
    for i in range(0,5)
        testline = infile.readline()
else:
    outfile.write(testline)
```

I get the following error that has me stumped:

```
File "convert.py", line 31
elseif testline == '\n':
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any thoughts? I can't figure out what is wrong with my elseif statement.

Comment: There is no `elseif` in Python.  You want `elif`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't `elseif` in python, it's `elif`.

Answer (score 5):

Others have pointed out it's `elif`. Also, you're missing a colon at the end of your `for` statement, and Python will probably complain about the *following* line. So now you don't have to come back and ask a separate question for that. :-)

If you just want to iterate over the lines in a file, though, a better way to do this is:

```
for testline in testfile:
   # do stuff with the line
```

You don't have to check for the end-of-file that way because the loop automatically ends when you reach the end of the file.

Comment: While the rest of the answers provided answer your question explicitly, kindall here is right, you should really follow his approach.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't 'elseif' it is 'elif' that you are looking for.

Furthermore there is another typo at the end of your for loop  `for i in range(0,5)` it needs a : at the end there.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try changing `elseif` to `elif`

And your indentation is stuffed from the 2nd line onwards